# Possibility of being asymptotically stable for a dynamical system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

The question is:

> Is there any function $\phi$ such that the system dfined by equations $$\dot{x}=-\sinh{x}\\ \dot{y}=-y\cosh{y}+x\phi(y)$$ has an asymptotically stable equilibrium point in the origin?

I think I should use LaSalle's theorem but I don't know how to find a proper potential function $V$ for this purpose.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, $\phi=0$, or actually any  "nice" (sub-linear?) differentiable function. Should the question not be the other way around, asking for $\phi$ that prevent the built-in stability?

Comment: @LutzLehmann No. Even when we are looking for global asymptotically stable?

Comment: The $x$ coordinate is independent of $y$ and converges always rapidly to zero. The same goes for the $y$ coordinate if $ϕ=0$. In the "endgame" with very small $x$, $y$ has to grow very rapidly, else the first term dominates. It could be that with $ϕ(y)=y^3\cosh(4y)$ or more rapidly growing there will not be global stability, for instance because the solution diverges in finite time for some initial points.